# update data every moment

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm working on a code that I can change information from server-side after a few seconds. for example:

I change the user points for being registered on the server, with the update method, but I want to change the points at the server at every time . I built a method to send information to the server and created a php file to update the information.I have no problem updating the data. But what's your suggestion to run update method after every changes.
To be clearer:
How to update data after points changed or TextView's text changed?

Comment: Are you asking to run some codes to be like real time updating?

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท Yes . Such as ranking table in real time or Change the scores of a person in time.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

you can use grpc and Rxjava

see below links:

https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/android.html

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to use tcp socket and send a message to client and tell them text has changed.
you can also use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for sending message from server and receiving in client.

this way you can receive the changes every time.

Comment: na dada . I mean, the information of a part ,
For example, a person's coins in the game
Every time it changes, it changes in the database as well.